# How to limit the memory used by my TOR navigator?

Tags: help

my tor navigator is using something like 260mo of memory. Is it possible to low this by a factor 5 ? What risks do I have ? What if Tor encounters a out of memory ? Thanks for helping !!

Comment: There's no way you'd be able to lower the amount of memory used that much.

Comment: What is your "tor navigator"?